# Golang not escape a string variable

Tags: string, go, escaping

We can use "`" to not escape a string:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main()  {
    fmt.Println(`abc\tdef`) // abc\tdef
}
```

But how to get or print a non-escaped string variable?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main()  {
    s := "abc\tdef"
    fmt.Println(s) // abc def
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `%#v` and `Sprintf`:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main()  {
    s := "abc\tdef"
    s = fmt.Sprintf("%#v", s)
    fmt.Println(s) // "abc\tdef"
}
```

`%#v`: a Go-syntax representation of the value

`Sprintf`: Sprintf formats according to a format specifier and returns the resulting string.